# Hoare triple: introducing Loop invariant and partial correctness

Tags: hoare-logic, imperative-programming, sequential-circuit

Hoare Triple formalizes program correctness, which contains postcondition,  program and precondition such as $\vdash P \{Q\} R$

Provided code snippet:

```
i := 0;
s := 0;
while i < N do
   s := s + max(arr[i]);
   i := i + 1;
od
```

The program's goal is to compute the **sum** of the maximum integers obtained from each element $arr[i]$, for $0 ≤ i < N$.

What is a proper Hoare Triple and loop invariant for this program? I’m stuck with prove of partial correctness because of loop invariant.

Comment: I cannot figure out the meaning of $\max(arr[i])$. Is $arr$ an array of arrays ?

Comment: Hint: the invariant expresses that $s$ holds the partial sum of the terms from $0$ to $i$ excluded.

Comment: What have you tried? Please check https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, arr ist array of arrays of integers